# Yii2 validation. Run filter on multiple attributes

Tags: validation, yii2

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['option_list', 'modifier'], 'filter', 'filter' => function($value) {
            // I can get the value but I don't know to which attribute it belongs (option_list or modifier)
        }],
    ];
}
```

How do I get an **attribute name** which is being processed? The only workaround that I found is to make separate filter for each attribute...

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter passed to validation function is `$attribute` so You can use it as follows

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['option_list', 'modifier'], function($attribute) {
            // use $this->$attribute for conditions or filtering
            // use $this->addError($attribute, '<error message>') for adding errors
        }],
    ];
}
```

see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#creating-validators

Comment: Yes, it is, but for validators. Notice, that I use "filter".

Comment: @SergeyOnishchenko yes, but actually `filter` is just one of Yii2 core validators. in own rule you can easily perform filtering too.

Comment: Yes this is ok, but in this case it's not so obvious that data modification is taking place instead of validation.

Comment: @SergeyOnishchenko it's just the semantic value of validation rule name. You can name your validation rule function `myFilter` and use it as filter. Or You can create own validation class with proper call semantic (maybe inherited from built-in [Filter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-filtervalidator.html))